# Redshift splitting multiple emails that are in a single row/column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a database in Redshift that has a field with emails. Some rows within that field have multiple emails for example 1 row could have j.smith@email.com and c.jones@email.com. The issue is that it is written like j.smith@email.comc.jones@email.com. I need to be able to separate the 2 emails (in this scenario between m and c). Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, but does not support unnest or array-to. I have tried

```
split_part(email, position('.com' in email)) as "test",
```

and

```
rtrim(replace(email, '@email.com', '@email.com'))
```

Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: Are you saying that there is _no separator_ between the email addresses? That will be hard, because some email addresses will end with `.com.au` or `.ninja`. There's no guaranteed way to separate them.

Comment: if you want help with this you will need to enhance your question, as per John's comment above you need to specify all of the email address domains that you have.  you should also double check your source/process to see whether you can add a delimiter or whether the delimiter is being removed somewhere along the way. you should also check the exact hex codes in your UTF string, you may have a non-displayable delimiter in there that you can use.

Comment: All of the email addresses end in.com and are @the same domain. It is for internal use.

Answer (score 0):

in `split_part`, you specify the separator and the 1-based index of the resulting array, not the position by which to split... just like this:

```
select split_part('j.smith@email.comc.jones@email.com','.com',1)||'.com';
select split_part('j.smith@email.comc.jones@email.com','.com',2)||'.com';
```